# Overriding Equals For Self Referencing Parent Child Objects

Tags: java, recursion, equals

I have a `Class` which holds **Parent-Child relationship** among its objects using self referencing

```
public class MyObject {

    private String name;

    private List<MyObject> childrens;

    private MyObject parent;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 13 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        hash = 13 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.childrens);
        hash = 13 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.parent);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final MyObject other = (MyObject) obj;

        if(!this.name.equalsIgnoreCase(other.name))
          return false;

        if(this.parent==null)
        {
            if(other.parent!=null)
            {  
                 return false;
            }
        }else if(!this.parent.equals(other.parent))
        {
           return false;
        }
        if(!allChildrenEqual(this,other))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean allChildrenEqual(MyObject aThis, MyObject other) {
        List<MyObject> children1=aThis.getChildrens();
        List<MyObject> children2=other.getChildrens();

        //Avoid infinite recusion can't use anything simple as 
        // list1 equals other list
        return true;
    }
```

I want to know how can I override equals properly which compares  hierarchy of these objects without going into infinite recursion and causing [StackOverflowError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html).

I have a feeling I am missing something really obvious.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will `parent` always be non-null (for top element?). Otherwise your code would return false or throw NPE even before checking for children.

Comment: @Codebender Sorry my fault missed that condition in code snippet.Editing it

Comment: If you're using `equalsIgnoreCase` to compare names, you need the hash of your `name` field to be case insensitive as well, otherwise you have a broken hash implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `equalsNoParentCheck()` method, then use that in the `allChildrenEqual()` method, and change the `equals()` method to use `equalsNoParentCheck()` and to perform the parent check.

Also, you have the same recursion issue in the `hashCode()` method. Just remove parent from the hashcode algorithm. Hashcodes don't *have* to be unique, just use best effort. It's unlikely that including parent would make much difference, overall, anyway.

Since you're using `Objects.hashCode()`, you might as well use `Objects.hash()`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(this.name, this.childrens); // Don't hash this.parent
}
```

Comment: And what would be the implementation of that method, Will it compare only current level and childrens not the parents?

Comment: It will do everything `equals()` does, except comparing `parent`. [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle then says to remove that common logic from `equals()` and just make `equals()` call the new `equalsNoParentCheck()`, in addition to doing the parent check itself. Do the class check+cast in `equals()` and make the parameter to `equalsNoParentCheck()` an actual `MyObject` type.

Answer (score 0):

I think that just putting the "base case of the recursive equivalence test", that is,

```
if (object == this) 
    return true;
```

at the first line of the equals() definition will prevent infinite recursion.